# MVC4 Create dropdownlists to capture business hours mins

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to capture Business Hours in my mvc4 application

for example I created dropdownlists for one of the days e.g. Monday

```
                     <div class="label-r">
                        Monday
                    </div>
                    <div>     


                    @Html.DropDownList("HoursMON", 
                        Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(),
                                    Text = i.ToString()}),"") 

                          @Html.DropDownList("MINMON", 
                        Enumerable.Range(0, 60).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(),
                                    Text = i.ToString() }),"")

                    @Html.DropDownList("AMMON", new List<SelectListItem>{
                            new SelectListItem {Text = "AM", Value="AM"},
                            new SelectListItem {Text = "PM", Value="PM"}},"")

                        :

                      @Html.DropDownList("HoursMON2", 
                        Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(),
                                    Text = i.ToString()}),"") 

                          @Html.DropDownList("MINMON2", 
                        Enumerable.Range(0, 60).Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(),
                                    Text = i.ToString() }),"")


                    @Html.DropDownList("AMMON2", new List<SelectListItem>{
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "AM", Value="AM"},
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "PM", Value="PM"}},"")
```

To created for the other days I need to duplicate the code x6 more times? doesnt seem right. Suggestions to make it clean to display the dropdownlists and to capture them in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a text block like so:

```
@{
    var hours = Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
       .Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString()});
}

@Html.DropDownList("HoursMON", hours, "")
@Html.DropDownList("HoursTUE", hours, "")
```

Etc.. you can do the same for the other variables.  If you are concerned about having to write the DropDownLists's for each day, then you can create a partial class and do this:

```
@Html.Partial("_Hours", "MON")
@Html.Partial("_Hours", "TUE")
```

Then in your _Hours.cshtml you would do something like this:

```
@model string

@{
    var hours = Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
       .Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i.ToString()});
}

@Html.DropDownList("Hours" + Model, hours, "")
```

Ideally, however, you should use a strongly typed model and use EditorTemplates instead..

Answer (score 0):

Create a partial view for your drop downs and use it for all seven days.